# How to process realtime progress of dd?

Tags: awk, pipe, dd, block-device, progress-information

I'm trying to process the realtime progress of dd, which, with pipes awareness, should be done via:

```
gzcat "$input" | dd bs="$block_size" count="$count" of="$output" 2>&1 | awk '/copied/ {print $1}'
gzcat "$input" | dd status=progress of="$output" 2>&1 | awk '/copied/ {print $1}'
```

but they don't print anything, until the end, when one line is printed.

I guess that this is because `dd` doesn't print any newline, therefore, awk doesn't get anything on the stdin.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change AWK’s record separator to split its input on carriage returns instead of newlines:

```
gzcat "$input" | dd status=progress of="$output" 2>&1 | awk -v RS='\r' '/copied/ {print $1}'
```